# Powershell issue with passing multiple parameters

Tags: powershell

I have the following function which compares a file version string to an actual file and returns 1 if the file is lower:

```
function FileVersionDetectionCheck() {
param([string]$file)
$fileversion = (get-item $file).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
$fileversionobject = [System.Version]$fileversion
$targetversion = [System.Version]::Parse("11.0.9700")

Write-Output "File Version:" $fileversionobject
Write-Output "Target Version:" $targetversion

if($fileversionobject -ge $targetversion) {
    return 0
}
else {
    return 1
}
}

FileVersionDetectionCheck("C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe")
```

This code works fine.  However, if I add a second string parameter...

```
function FileVersionDetectionCheck() {
param([string]$file,[string]$version)
$fileversion = (get-item $file).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
$fileversionobject = [System.Version]$fileversion
#$targetversion = [System.Version]::Parse("11.0.9700")
$targetversion = [System.Version]$version

Write-Output "File Version:" $fileversionobject
Write-Output "Target Version:" $targetversion

if($fileversionobject -ge $targetversion) {
    return 0
}
else {
    return 1
}
}

FileVersionDetectionCheck("C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe", 
"11.0.9700")
```

It errors out with:

get-item : Cannot find path 'C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe 11.0.9700' because it does not exist.

Seems to be reading both parameters as a single string.

As far as I can tell this is a valid way to pass multiple parameters to a function.  Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell functions are not like methods in other languages. Remove the parentheses from your function name `function FileVersionDetectionCheck()` and then when you call the function do not use commas or parenthesis. For example

`myFunction firstParam secondParam`

With your code from above it would look like this.

`FileVersionDetectionCheck "C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" "11.0.9700"`

Comment: your first statement is really arguable, python, bash, cmd, powershell all work exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Jason's answer, here is what it would look like with both parameters

```
function FileVersionDetectionCheck 
{
    param([string]$file,[string]$version)
    $fileversion = (get-item $file).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    $fileversionobject = [System.Version]$fileversion
    #$targetversion = [System.Version]::Parse("11.0.9700")
    $targetversion = [System.Version]$version

    Write-Output "File Version:" $fileversionobject
    Write-Output "Target Version:" $targetversion

    if($fileversionobject -ge $targetversion) {
        return 0
    }else {
        return 1
    }
}

FileVersionDetectionCheck -file "C:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" -version "11.0.9700")
```

Comment: this part is cut off for some reason.. `-version "11.0.9700"`